# What is the name of the area, controls and instruments where a loadmaster sits?

Tags: military, cargo, antonov-225, lockheed-c-5, boeing-c-17

In a HLA (such as an  Antonov, C5M, or C17 Globemaster III), what is the name of the area where the loadmaster sits?

Also, what are the names of the controls and instruments that the loadmaster uses in these types of aircraft?

Comment: I've reworded your question to be a little more gramatically correct, hopefully I have not changed the meaning. Could you clarify what the abbreviation HLA means - I assume something like Heavy Lift Aircraft but couldn't be sure.

Comment: thank you for correcting it and yes, HLA I mean stands for (Heavy Lift Aircraft)

Answer (score 4):

In the C-17:

It called the loadmasters station:

> Master Sgt. Skip Hurley, 62nd Operations Group standards and evaluations superintendent, briefs Master Chief Petty Officer Mark Rudes, command master chief of U.S. Pacific Command, Oct. 29, 2012, about the **loadmaster's station** aboard a C-17 Globemaster III aircraft

https://www.airforcemedicine.af.mil/News/Photos/igphoto/2000100799/

[image: Loadmaster station in the front of the cargo bay, next to the stairs leading to the cockpit]

https://www.dvidshub.net/image/7239666/89-loadmaster-path-become-c-17-pilot